# XML drawable cut corner instead of round

Tags: android, android-layout, android-drawable, android-vectordrawable, xml-drawable

Similar to the M3 `cornerFamily` feature, how to achieve it via XML drawables?

[image]

Current code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="@color/colorWhiteDark_Primary"/>
    <corners android:radius="10dp"/>
</shape>
```

Comment: https://material.io/components/dialogs/android#theming-dialogs if you are using dialog then this is helpful.

Comment: No "cut corner" drawable AFAIK. If it must be an XML file, then consider a bitmap drawable or a nine-patch drawable. See [Drawable Resources](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource).

Comment: @SandeshKhutalSaheb unfortunately I am using this for a action menu. I am already using this style to my dialogs and want to make it available in context menu or action menu dialog as well

Comment: Try using this repository https://github.com/Devlight/CornerCutLinearLayout, may be this helps to get your thing done.